# Why is there a /usr/local/opt directory created by Homebrew and should I use it?

Tags: macos, homebrew

I am quite new at using homebrew and I am trying to figure out how it works to use some libraries (boost, gsl, openblas for example) in my own project.

I have understood that each formula is installed by Homebrew in /usr/local/Cellar/ and then symlinked in usr/local/bin, usr/local/lib, usr/local/include, so it seems, excepts for keg-only formulas so it does not mess with already installed libraries by the OS (cf. [Understand homebrew and keg-only dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17015285/understand-homebrew-and-keg-only-dependencies) for example). But I found out that every formula is also linked to a /usr/local/opt directory.

So my question is why is there this /usr/local/opt directory (it is kind of redundant), and what path do I have to use for using formulas (usr/local/Cellar or usr/local/ or usr/local/opt basically) ?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

It provides a path for a formula's contents that does not change across version upgrades.

Consider this scenario: Say you build `libfoo.dylib` with Homebrew. It is version 2.0.0, and so it lives at `/usr/local/Cellar/libfoo/2.0.0/lib/libfoo.dylib`. You want to link to it from another program you are building, so you pass `-L/usr/local/Cellar/libfoo/2.0.0/lib -lfoo` to `gcc`. Your program compiles. Later on, you upgrade to libfoo 2.0.1 and remove v2.0.0. Now `/usr/local/Cellar/libfoo/2.0.0/lib/libfoo.dylib` no longer exists, and your program no longer runs, because it can't dynamically load libfoo.

That's okay. `libfoo.dylib` is also available at `/usr/local/lib/libfoo.dylib`. It's a symlink to the latest version of libfoo, so it should always be present. So you pass `-L/usr/local/lib -lfoo` to your program and compile it. Later you upgrade to libfoo 2.0.1. No problem, because `/usr/local/lib/libfoo.dylib` is still present and points to the v2.0.1 copy.

That's great, and Homebrew existed with just that system for a while. The problem is, some formula are "keg-only", so they are not symlinked from `/usr/local`. (Generally they are keg-only because they shadow a version of a library that ships with OS X, and superseding OS X libraries can cause problems.) Say you want to link to a keg-only version of the library. It's not symlinked from `/usr/local/lib`, so you have to give the full path to the version installed in `/usr/local/Cellar`, which is brings you back to the first problem listed above.

`/usr/local/opt` solves this problem. It provides a place for the current version of *all* formulae to be symlinked, regardless of whether they are keg-only or not. Now, when you want to compile your program, you can use `-L/usr/local/opt/libfoo/lib -lfoo`, and your program will link to the latest version of libfoo, even if you upgrade it and even if it is keg-only.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! (and for helping me reopening this question by the way) So I guess the safest choice is to always use /usr/local/opt, but then why Homebrew still use /usr/local/lib to create symlinks for non keg-only ?

Answer (score 6):

Just to complement mipadi answer.

From an article aptly named '[/usr/local/opt](http://www.extellisys.com/articles/usr-local-opt)'

> Storing files in consistent locations is an important part of keeping
> a system clean and maintainable. On most Linux systems, the majority
> of software is installed using a package manager. A package manager
> tracks the files that are installed, so it can update and remove
> software with minimal side-effects.
>
> There are times, however, when software that is not available through
> the package manager must be installed. To minimize the side-effects on
> the filesystem, such software is installed within the /usr/local
> directory. UNIX-style installation of software puts files in the bin,
> lib, share, etc. subdirectories under the local root, but it is very
> common to install software into package-specific directories and add
> soft-links from the local root instead. Doing so allows for easy
> removal of the software—simply remove the package-specific directory
> as well as any links pointing into it.
>
> Some software provides local installation instructions that promote
> creating a package-specific directory directly in /usr/local. This
> does not promote good organization, as it mixes UNIX hierarchy
> directories with package-specific directories. Installation of
> software into package-specific directories is already done elsewhere,
> in the /opt directory, and it would therefore make sense to follow the
> same conventions and put locally installed package-specific
> directories in a /usr/local/opt directory.
>
> Including a version number in the directory name is not required, but
> it is good practice for locally-installed software because it allows
> multiple versions to be installed and tested simultaneously. To run a
> specific version of the software, run the executable under the package
> directory directly. Any version can be made the default by controlling
> which executable is linked to from /usr/local/bin. For example, a new
> version of software can be installed and tested without removing the
> old version. When the new version is ready, the link in /usr/local/bin
> can be updated to point to it. The old version of the software can
> then be removed when it is no longer needed.

Source: Copyright © 2014 Extellisys

Answer (score 0):

I found that in `/usr/local/opt`(in my own macOS file system) there were many symlinks related to other programs, such as `openssl`, `gnutls`, and so on. So I think this(`/usr/local/opt`) specific directory is not created just for HomeBrew, and it might be applied to more broader range of executable procedure.

BTW 1: I consulted the homepage of the "Filesystem Hierarchy Standard (FHS)". I didn't find the description about `/usr/local/opt` in the "Chapter 4. The /usr Hierarchy". It's somewhat curious.

BTW 2: I have installed the GNU Stow by HomeBrew. When I input the command `brew --prefix stow` the Terminal displays the path `/usr/local/opt/stow`. Then I try to open it using command `open /usr/local/opt/stow` in Terminal. It opens a directory whose path is `/usr/local/Cellar/stow/2.3.1`.