# Unable to link BLAS and LAPACK in makefile using gfortran on MacOS

Tags: macos, makefile, fortran, gnu-make, gfortran

I am trying to link against the BLAS and LAPACK libraries using the makefile

```
FFLAGS = -O0 -fcheck=all -ffree-line-length-none

PROJECTDIR = .
srcdir     = $(PROJECTDIR)/src

debug:
    gfortran -c $(FFLAGS) $(srcdir)/foo.f90
    gfortran -c $(FFLAGS) $(srcdir)/bar.f90
    gfortran -c $(FFLAGS) $(srcdir)/foobar.f90
    gfortran -o debug *.o -lblas -llapack
    rm -f *.o *.mod
```

When I run make I get that `ld: library not found for -lblas`. I ran `brew info openblas` and saw that

```
openblas is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because macOS provides BLAS in Accelerate.framework.

For compilers to find openblas you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openblas/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openblas/include"
```

So, I modified (also based [on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35337601/why-is-there-a-usr-local-opt-directory-created-by-homebrew-and-should-i-use-it)) the makefile to include the LDFLAGS

```
FFLAGS = -O0 -fcheck=all -ffree-line-length-none
LDFLAGS=  -L/usr/local/opt/lapack/lib -llapack -L/usr/local/opt/openblas/lib -lblas

debug:
    gfortran -c $(FFLAGS) $(srcdir)/foo.f90
    gfortran -c $(FFLAGS) $(srcdir)/bar.f90
    gfortran -c $(FFLAGS) $(srcdir)/foobar.f90
    gfortran -o debug *.o $(LDFLAGS)
    rm -f *.o *.mod
```

Now I get that `ld: library not found for -lSystem`. I also tried using the suggested Accelerate framework by using `LDFLAGS = -framework Accelerate`. When I did that I received that `ld: framework not found Accelerate`.

Any suggestions for correctly linking these libraries is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour] and use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. Fortran 90 is just one particular very old version of the standard.

Comment: @VladimirF Thank you. I have now taken the tour and will tag all my future Fortran questions using the suggested tag.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the answer of Mead from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56156520/gfortran-error-ld-library-not-found-for-lsystem-when-trying-to-compile) and ran `brew install gfortran` and that solved the issue for me.