# How to force cmake to link against homebrew keg-only libraries

Tags: c++, cmake, homebrew, readline

I have third party cmake project that depends on gnu readline library. So I installed readline by `brew install readline`. The problem is, readline is a [keg-only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17016758/811098) formula and cmake tries to link it against `libedit` which shadows `libreadline` but it lacks some functionalities.

My question is, how can I force cmake to prefer brew version of this library over the system library?

Also, since this would be a osx only problem, it would be great if solution can be applied via command line (instead of changing CMakeList.txt).

Answer (score 1):

Excerpt from `brew info readline`:

```
For compilers to find readline you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/readline/include"

For pkg-config to find readline you may need to set:
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/readline/lib/pkgconfig"
```

CMake uses pkg-config for finding a library, so the second paragraph should apply.