# How to run Python2 after Homebrew Update?

Tags: python, python-2.7, homebrew

I used to have python and python3 installed. So I could decide which python to use. I now updated python with homebrew and it migrated python3 to python. How do I run python2 now?

When I check the installation I get:

```
$ python -V
Python 3.6.4
$ python2 -V
-bash: python2: command not found
$ python3 -V
Python 3.6.4
```

If I try to simply reinstall python2 I get:

```
$ brew install python2
Warning: python@2 2.7.14_1 is already installed
```

However I cannot use python2.

```
python2: command not found
```

Comment: Use the old, out-of-date, Apple-supplied one with `/usr/bin/python`

Comment: @MarkSetchell If I use python I runs python 3. It seems that homebrew has overwritten the command.

Comment: I didn't say to use `python`. I said to use `/usr/bin/python -V`

Comment: @MarkSetchell that works, thanks! However, how do I install packages now? I used to do everything with pip, but pip is now for python 3. `/usr/bin/pip -V` does not work.

Comment: You can execute `pip` as a module from the Python you wish to affect... `/usr/bin/python -m pip install --user somePackage`

Comment: @MarkSetchell there seems to be no pip with the applied supplied python: `/usr/bin/python: No module named pip`

Comment: @MarkSetchell is there any way to have 'python' point to `/usr/bin/python` python3 point to brew's python3, as before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the symbolic link that Homebrew makes from the Cellar to the actual bin directory on your path.

Use:

```
brew link python2
```

to fix that.

You may run into a warning:

> Warning: python@2 is keg-only and must be linked with --force Note that doing so can interfere with building software.

See the accepted answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17015285/understand-homebrew-and-keg-only-dependencies) for some details on that.

In most case, you can then safely use

```
brew link --force python2
```

if you're not planning building your own libraries that require the source code (`libpython.so` and `Python.h`) for Python 2.
If you do require the source code, you'll need to provide the include paths and library paths to e.g. `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.14_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7` and `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.14_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/`. But that's a different topic or question.

---

To use pip for Homebrew's Python 2, best to use is

```
python2 -m pip <command>
```

Then you can clearly see what Python your `pip` command goes with, and keep it apart from Python 3 (which would be `python3 -m pip`).

---

### Note

If you have Homebrew problems, first cause of action is to run

```
brew doctor
```

The error messages are usually quite helpful to fix at some of the problems.

Comment: Using `brew link python2` gives `Warning: python@2 is keg-only and must be linked with --force Note that doing so can interfere with building software.`

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni that's a related but different issue, and only relevant if you run into actual problems. An explanation is at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17015285/understand-homebrew-and-keg-only-dependencies

Comment: Ok, but as `python@2` alias `python2` is now keg-only I wonder how `brew link python2` could ever work?

Comment: And using `brew link --force` results in warnings in `brew doctor`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that Homebrew has changed things again - as I had both python 2.7.x and 3.x.x installed through Homebrew for the same reasons. After the initial update, `python2` would no longer work, but if you used `python@2` you would get access as before.

Now however, they have seemed to partially revert some of these changes. Calling `python` now points to the keg-only 2.7.x homebrew installation instead of the 3.x.x installation. In addition, `python@2` no longer works, but `python2` no does. `python3` still points to the 3.x.x installation as before.

[**NOTE:** I have not modified my ~/.bash_profile for any of these changes to occur.]